# Making port forwarded to EC2 machine available to other machines

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, port-forwarding

I'm using Apache Zeppelin and having the port forwarded from the EMR master node to an EC2 instance (running Amazon Linux). When I RDP into the EC2 instance, I can connect to Zeppelin by going to http://localhost:. However when I try to connect to Zeppelin from another machine using http://:port, I get a connection refused error. I've tried many different ports, all to no avail.

What am I missing?

Comment: Security group settings? Firewall on the instance? Does Zeppelin have to be set up to listen to external connections?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I believe the problem was I was using local port forwarding from EC2 to EMR instead of remote port forwarding from EMR to EC2. I'll give it a shot and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to do remote port forwarding from the EMR cluster (to forward the local port on the EMR cluster master node to the remote port on the EC2 instance) instead of local port forwarding on the EC2 instance (which was forwarding the local port from the EC2 instance to the remote port on the EMR cluster master node).

So, the command looks like:

```
ssh -R remoteEc2Port:localhost:localEmrPort ec2-user@ec2-ip
```

Yippee!